# gtk allow background processes

Tags: python, gtk

I'm creating a program in python, and use GTK for part of it.
Whenever GTK opens, it causes the whole program to stop responding, and not move on to the next process. Ideally, i would like it if the gtk window opened independently to the rest of the program, since the GTK window is just to display information, and the functionality is text based

Is there any way to continue executing the python program, after the GTK window opened. I can't find anything in the pygtk manuals

Any help would be great, thansks

Comment: Run the GTK main loop in a separate thread?

Comment: You should check out Python's `threading` module.

Answer (score 0):

If your program has a Gtk UI then the program is supposed to be driven by the GTK main loop. You may be able to run a gtk main loop in a secondary thread, but that it not really a supported configuration and you may run into many more problems

Comment: Running the GTK main loop from a non-main thread is OK as long as all GTK calls are made from that same thread. If the rest of the program is text-based and the GTK window is really "just to display information", he could spawn another thread, copy the data it needs, and run the main loop there.